# AngularJS - Find end of collapse animation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple problem with [angularui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)'s `collapse` directive. I have a `<select>` menu. When the someone changes the menu, the content changes. However, I would like to add an animation before applying these changes. Specifically, I would like for the section to collapse and uncollapse before showing the new content. I can collapse it, but I would like to know how to detect when the collapse has finished so I can uncollapse it.

I could use the `$timeout` method that I currently use, but it feels "hackish" and "incorrect," because if the time for the collapse animation changes, then I have to change the time again.

Relavent code:

```
.directive("myBufferAnimation", function($timeout) {
    var ignoreFirst = true;
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("selectBuffer", function(newValue) {
            if (ignoreFirst) {
                ignoreFirst = false;
                return;
            }


            scope.toCollapse = true;    
            // Detect end of animation here?
            // Bogus solution, as this just waits for one second rather than listening for the end of animation
            $timeout(function() {
               scope.selected = newValue;
               scope.toCollapse = false;
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
});
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/mcp8L0nn/) illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the angularui bootstrap's collapse directive, it does the animation using the $transition service but it doesn't expose away to hook into the promise return by the service.  It does however change the class name of the element that has the `collapse` directive on it. You can use that to determine when the collapse animation has completed by putting a watch on the class attribute of the element.

Below is a working example of the code watching the class on the element.  I made a change to use `ng-change` to execute the animation instead of the watching the `selectBuffer`.  This eliminates the need for the `ignoreFirst` variable.

```js
angular.module("testApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]).controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
  // This would actually be fetched from an ajax call
  $scope.data = [{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "content": "Content 1"
  }, {
    "title": "The Second Title",
    "content": "Some content goes here"
  }, {
    "title": "Title 3",
    "content": "Content 3"
  }];
  $scope.selected = $scope.data[0];
  $scope.selectBuffer = $scope.data[0];
  $scope.toCollapse = false;
}).directive("myBufferAnimation", function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.valueChanged = function() {
      scope.toCollapse = true;
      // save off the unregister method returned from $watch call.
      var unregisterWatch = scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.attr('class');
      }, function(newClass, oldClass) {
        // If the newClass is 'collapse' and the oldClass is 'collapsing'
        // this means that the collapsing animation has completed.
        if (newClass.indexOf("collapse") !== -1 && oldClass.indexOf("collapsing") !== -1) {
          scope.selected = scope.selectBuffer;
          scope.toCollapse = false;
          // unregister the $watch on the class attribute
          // since it is no longer needed.
          unregisterWatch();
        }
      });
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <select ng-options="opt as opt.title for opt in data" ng-model="selectBuffer" ng-change="valueChanged()"></select>
      <br />
      <div my-buffer-animation="" collapse="toCollapse" class="test">
        <h1>{{selected.title}}</h1>

        <p>{{selected.content}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I notice that you use `newClass === "collapse"`. Will this work even if there are other classes (because then `newClass` might be `"collapse my-custom-class"` or something, right?)

Comment: Update on last comment: I added `test-class` to the `div` with `my-buffer-animation` directive and the above code stopped working, but I think this can be solved using `element.hasClass` or an equivalent.

Comment: I tried testing you suggested changes but I was getting an error in the browser I was using, this maybe due to `classList` being used and the way angularjs gets the old value to pass to the watch function.  I instead used `indexOf` to determine if the class names exist which should handle having multiple class names.  `indexOf` may not be robust enough for every situation but it should suffice for what you're doing.