# When accordion is open or collapsed (transition ended)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap, iscroll

is it possible to know or intercept when an accordion is open or closed with angular-ui-bootstrap, only when transition is ended?

So, when one accordion content is open i can refresh iScroll instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js

There does not seem to be any event triggered on `collapseDone()` or `expandDone()` that you can hook into.

The only way you can really do this is to watch when the class 'collapsing' exists (meaning collapsing is happening), then you know collapsing is over when that class goes away.

```
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $('.panel-collapse').hasClass('collapsing');
      }, function(status) {
        if ($scope.collapsing && !status) {
          console.log('done collapsing');
        }
        $scope.collapsing = status;
      });
```

Similar question: [AngularJS - Find end of collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196995/angularjs-find-end-of-collapse-animation)